# How to create multiple directories and populate them with files

Tags: linux, bash, files, directory, xargs

I want to make some directory trees and populate each end of the tree with a text file with random content.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

echo "Generating test folders"

mkdir -p ./parent_{0..9}/child_{0..9}
head -c 100 /dev/urandom | xargs echo >> ./parent_{0..9}/child_{0..9}/test.txt

echo "done"
```

When executing, I get this error:

```
./gen-test.sh: line 8: ./parent_{0..9}/child_{0..9}/test.txt: ambiguous redirect
```

What am I doing wrong and what could be a smarter approach to this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that what you're doing wrong doesn't work is because redirection and filename generation is handled by the shell, not by xargs.

When you write

```
foo > foo.out
```

then the shell will run `foo` for you, capture its standard output, and write that to `foo.out`.

If you run

```
foo | xargs bar > bar.out
```

then the shell will run `foo` for you, capture its standard output, run `xargs`, and send the standard output from `foo` into the standard input of `xargs`. At some point, `xargs` will run `bar`, and pass it the data it received on standard input as arguments, and it will do so in a way that causes the standard output of `bar` to be indistinguishable of the standard output of `xargs`. The shell will capture that standard output, and write it to `bar.out`.

Your arguments of `./parent_{0..9}/child_{0..9}/test.txt` are also interpreted by the shell. It removes that argument, and replaces it by the filenames that would be generated by that pattern, so that the `mkdir` command line becomes something like (`...` added for brevity):

```
mkdir -p ./parent_0/child_0/test.txt ./parent_0/child_1/test.txt ./parent_0/child_2/test.txt ... ./parent_1/child_0/test.txt ... ./parent_9/child_9/test.txt
```

Later on, you run

```
head -c 100 /dev/urandom | xargs # ...
```

which means you read 100 bytes of random data, turn that into command-line arguments to `echo` by way of `xargs`, which will then attempt to output that data (which is unlikely to go well, given that it is binary data and we're talking about a command line here).

Finally, the shell sees `>>`, which it interprets it as an appending redirect, followed by the same pattern; so that means the redirect becomes

```
>> /parent_0/child_0/test.txt /parent_0/child_1/test.txt # and so on
```

but you can't do that; you can only redirect to one file at a time (this is the "ambiguous redirect" error you see).

The easiest fix is to loop over the files:

```
for file in /pattern_0/child_0/test.txt; do
    head -c 100 /dev/urandom > $file
done
```

because any solution that uses xargs will require echo to turn command-line arguments into standard output, only to use xargs to turn the same standard output back into command-line arguments again, which is obviously inefficient.